# Spring MVC context beans: Is it bad to modify objects from getBean()? Threading concern

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-mvc

I have a bunch of objects that I always use, but on every page load I change certain properties of the object.

For example:
/bob/dave-10

Will show information about bob's child named dave at age 10, as such in the controller:

```
Child child = (Child)context.getBean("child_"+childName);
child.setAge(childAge);
model.addAttribute("child", child);
return "jsp_page";
```

But a person can also go to:
/bob/dave-11
to see dave's information at age 11.

At dave-10, I change a Child object's age property to 10. At dave-11, I change the same property to 11.

I fear that this may cause a race condition where two+ people visit different ages for dave, and one person will receive the other's page.

Can this happen? Or should I not worry? I am not using synchronized/thread locking anywhere. If this will be a problem, how should I best approach this? By cloning every object? Or is there a way to create a new object every time I getBean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there a way to create a new object every time I getBean?

Yes. Make the bean prototype-scoped, using `@Scope("prototype")`, or the corresponding XML.

But I feel this class shouldn't be a Spring component at all, and you should simply create a new instance every time you need one.

Comment: It should be a bean if there injection of another beans is required.